How to troubleshoot a Module Manifest?
I have a small PowerShell module that loads fine without a psd1 file. As soon as a psd1 file is in the root of the module folder, the module fails to (auto) load without error. Also Test-ModuleManifest gives no errors.
What is wrong with this .psd1 which prevents it from loading the .psm1?
@{
    ModuleVersion = '1.0.0'
    GUID = '30197a8a-2ad7-446d-9cfd-5ce440efde93'
    Author = 'Me'
    CompanyName = 'Us'
    Copyright = '(c) Us. All rights reserved.'
    Description = 'Get and Set Display Settings'
    PowerShellVersion = '7.0'
    FunctionsToExport = @(
        'Set-DisplayResolution',
        'Set-DisplayRefreshRate',
        'Get-DisplayResolution'
    )
    CmdletsToExport = @()
}



What happens if you manually import-module “./my.psd1”? If that works or gives an error that would help identify if it’s a problem with the module itself or the auto-load feature…

And you could try adding rootmodule = "./my.psm1" to your *.psd1

@mclayton Nothing happens, No message but the module is not loaded

@mclayton The command 'RootModule' is not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.

have a look at this tio.run - https://tio.run/##dVJRT4MwEH7nVzT4wJZYBIebezBhcbr4MGM256NJQ49BUihpi4MYfzu2lJkZ5720@b7v7ru7tuIHEDIDxnDCBXSdBKVvpYJSIde/Klq/kjR0Uew68aeDdKw5rRm86bScl@gOeaEf@IHXc6vd09JAkyCcz8gtwdeEznAUTSmeJynFNwlEUQAphfnEZixqlXFhctZgkXteVKRsn0kBBt7JI1y1It9nyoCjZIx20kcLxlAPSiRAgvgA6lv5EmQi8koNPa5AIVJStNXnMpcVI625q7zcD/VfzCa2ZhMno03NYD0tOFdFP7nGj4spQrcnL9D7EFb8WJeJcZav/KGpuDA9x6OeMuFpZzx0sQHJWW3E3uU/glSPlm2IglPF6myJnh/bfRWUgfrdwdj5ctzYcc49cmEfOR1aR0ZDrYH4MXDsFziIXAHOuNTpTdO4Q9m8ME54WNPJ77GOf6p13Tc

it calls a dummy set-displayresolution that just outputs “xxx”. If you comment out the rootmodule (previously moduletoprocess in earlier versions of Powershell - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.4#module-manifest-elements ) it fails to find the command - maybe that will give a pointer. (I had to change the “Powershell version” to 6 as that’s what tio.run uses…)

have you created the manifest with New-ModuleManifest?

@Eldo.Ob originally, yes

The name of the modulefolder, psm1-filename, Filename and name of the modulemanifest are the same?
Wht error do you get, while importing your module. Use the switch -Verbose.

No error message. That the Problem.


Building on mclayton's helpful comments:
Test-ModuleManifest only tests the internal consistency of a module manifest.
It does not test the validity of a PowerShell module as a whole.
Since your manifest uses a FunctionsToExport entry in order to designate functions to export, the implication is that your module is lacking a RootModule entry that points to a script-module file (*.psm1) in which these functions are defined (implemented).
See also: this answer to a later, conceptually related question of yours.
